# Magento VAT (tax) rates not working correctly on displayed prices: VAT is added even catalog prices are including tax

Tags: magento

I'm setting up a store and have already got prices on products.  NOW I'm looking at the VAT issue and have set up tax details under Sales > Tax to apply a UK VAT rate of 20%.

The prices which have been entered in the product catalogue are all inclusive of VAT and so in System > Configuration > Sales > Tax I've set 'Catalog Prices -> Including Tax' and 'Display Product Prices In Catalog -> Including Tax'.

Despite 'Catalog Prices -> Including Tax' the system seems to believe that the price stored is exclusive of VAT so, for example, a product of £10.50 (inclusive) is showing as £10.50 PLUS VAT i.e. £12.60, although the catalogue entry price is showing as £10.50 GBP Inc.Tax

In fact, even if I say 'Catalog Prices -> Excluding Tax', it doesn't seem to make any difference.

It seems that no matter what I tell it, it thinks my catalogue prices are exclusive of VAT.  Am I missing a setting somewhere?

Magento ver. 1.7.0.2

Tax setup details:-

```
Tax Class = Retail Customers (the only class)
Product Class = Taxable Goods (all products assigned to this)
Tax Zone = UK TAX = 20%
Tax Rule = Retail Customers / Taxable Goods / UK Tax
```

Comment: Yes, you have missed something. I am betting its the classic gotcha, the seemingly unrelated shipping origin. You have to system - configuration - sales - shipping settings - origin.  Or similar, sorry I'm on my phone and can't check it bit I bet thats it!!

Comment: That is a bet you'd win - exactly right!  It's actually where and what you said, so now I can move on to the next set of problems.

Comment: Excellent! I'll turn that guess into a proper answer later today :) Glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No shame at all in missing this setting - unless you knew about it you wouldn't think it would be related to the display of tax inclusive prices.

System -> Configuration -> Sales - Shipping settings - Origin

(if you are using the UK language pack replace Shipping Settings with Delivery Settings).

Comment: I'd not come across the UK language pack... would it let me change tax to VAT?  At least the users would be more likely to understand it then?  What does it let me do?  Its overview only repeats what it's called.

Comment: It doesn't let you do anything - Magento translations reside in app/locale/* - if you have set your default store origin to UK (ie store code GB) and have the GB language pack in app/locale/ then tax becomes VAT, cart becomes basket, shipping becomes delivery etc. Same for all languages. You can modify the translation too of course.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Makes sense and worth while getting.  Many thanks once again.

Comment: @McNab Hi, I know this is not the most recent thread, but I'm hoping you could help. I've followed the instructions here but it still displays the incl. tax and excl. tax as the same, what other causes could there be to this rather annoying bug?

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect!

Comment: Also don't forget to reindex prices even if they don't show as in need of reindexing.