# Magento - Tax Excluding Total and Including Total the same

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have spent nearly 2 days now trying to get these damn tax rules to work in Magento.

I have a product. I have one Product Tax Class. I have one Customer Group. I have one Tax Zone (UK @ 20%). I have one Tax Rule for this zone, Product Tax Class and Customer Group.

The tax settings are as follows:

[image: Magento Tax Settings]

When I add a product to my cart, the product price is £695. The Cart totals are as follows:

[image: Magento Shopping Cart Totals]

This is clearly wrong. If the product price is £695 and I've specified that this price is excluding tax, then 20% should be added to this cost. At the very least, the two Grand Total costs should be different!

The two very last things I've done were to delete the cache manually (via FTP) and to re-index all the indexes.

Comment: I see this is an old question kicked up by an edit - this answer may be relevant though - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192681/magento-vat-tax-rates-not-working-correctly-on-displayed-prices

Comment: Looks like that might well have been the problem! Thanks McNab.

Answer (score 0):

There are two settings to break this configuration into.

1. For Tax display.
2. For Tax calculation.

If you check your shopping cart display setting you will find you stated display price, display subtotal and display shipping to include taxes.

Play with those display settings and you will get result.